# convert cvs to database and graphing data: advice on optimisation

Tags: objective-c, c, database, sqlite

Was hoping for some advice on best practice here. Working in objective C and Xcode.

I made a "FileConverter" class which has a method to reads a cvs file with 7 columns of float values into a SQLite database (after verifying the data and parsing it).

The way I have done this is to load the whole file into an NSString, then split into row components, then split each row into column components (saving the result as a 2x2 NSArray.

I then open database and copy the array into the sqlite database.  I'm using the TEXT datatype for storage at the moment.  Once there, I plan to graph the data.

It seems to check and convert the cvs ok.  However if the csv is quite long ( say 10,000 rows), I get the spinning wheel for several seconds while it does its work.  For shorter files it converts almost instantly.

Ultimately, at the point the user clicks "Convert CSV", I will also be running another method which will graph the data and I expect this will result in huge delay while it reads the sql database, assembles the data into CGPoints and then draws into the graph view.

My question is about how best to optimise the process, so it can handle the larger files without spinning wheels appearing.  Is this possible?

a) Using NSStrings and NSArrays certainly makes the job of reading and splitting up the data super simple and makes verifying the data easy.  Is this the best way?  Should I  malloc a float array instead?

b) I'm working on the basis that by saving the data as TEXT values in the database, converting them to CGFloat values will be straightforward, but realise this will add processing time.

c)  I'm imagining that a sqlite3 database would be a faster way for getting the data when I come to graphing it, but I could also simply copy the cvs file and parse it at the point of graphing the data.

Really appreciate advice on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main thread runs the UI, and you're trying to do your computation (CSV Computations) on the main thread making the UI hang (not updating) making the OS invoke the spinning wheel. To avoid this you need to move your compute intensive operations to secondary threads.

When the csv file is small, a synchronous operation is able to perform the csv computation and update the UI immediately. In case of big files, the UI (app window) waits for the computations to finish before the UI can be updated. In such cases you need to asynchronously compute the csv calculations on a background thread. There are many ways to achieve this, the most popular being Apple's GCD.

The following link, Apple's guide to non blocking UI explains it in detail:

[Link to Apple's non blocking guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/UnblockUI.html)

[Link to GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html)

Comment: thanks johnny peter.  reading the links you posted right now.

Comment: Theres probably additional things I can do to optimise I imagine, but I just ran the GCD on the CSVfileLoader and it worked a treat.  Big thanks and tick